# CSS height problem

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
<div style="height: 500px; background: #f00; display: table;">
  <div style="display: table-cell;">
    <div style="display: table; height: 100%;">
      <div style="display: table-cell;">asd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in Opera, the div (who has height set to 100%) has a height of 19px. Why does the 100% not make it 500px in height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="height: 500px; background: #f00; display: table;">
  <div style="display: table-cell;height:100%">
    <div style="display: table; height: 100%;">
      <div style="display: table-cell;">asd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should set the second div height as well.

Comment: Just for personal interest, won't DIV number two do a height: auto; and expand to the height of its contents? It always has done in tests.

Comment: Some browsers need explicit definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
<div style="height: 500px; background: #f00; display: table;">
   <div style="display: table-cell;">
     <div style="display: table; height: 100%; background: #00f;">
       <div style="display: table-cell;">asd</div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

You will see that it is the full height in Opera.

The text just won't fill the area.